# Loop through div to change background color of a specific child

Tags: javascript, css, for-loop

I am currently help develop a sports page that brings in data for different players on different teams. The idea is to loop through a group of "cards", find a div that has a background team color applied to it, and change that color based on the team name inside of it. I began with this for loop below (the client wants pure JS):

```
var containerDiv = document.getElementsByClass("my-card");
var innerDivs = containerDiv.getElementsByClassName("card-details-team-container");
for(var i=0; i<innerDivs.length; i++)
{
     if ( innerDivs[i].innerHTML = "Team 1" ) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
     } else if ( innerDivs[i].innerHTML = "Team 2" ) {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     } else {
        this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
     }
}
```

This does not work, and I am not sure why? It seems to be wired up correctly, but the team colors are not changing. Also, this data is being brought in on button click in real time so I am wondering, maybe the JS can't crawl the data because this HTML is not on the page when the page initially loads? Here is my snippet:

```js
var containerDiv = document.getElementsByClass("my-card");
var innerDivs = containerDiv.getElementsByClassName("card-details-team-container");
for(var i=0; i<innerDivs.length; i++)
{
     if ( innerDivs[i].innerHTML = "Team 1" ) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
     } else if ( innerDivs[i].innerHTML = "Team 2" ) {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     } else {
      this.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
     }
}
```

```css
.my-card { float: left; }
.card-details-team-container { background: #ff0000; }
```

```html
<div class="my-grid-of-cards">
  <div class="my-card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
      <p class="card-details-name">Player 1</p>
      <div class="card-details-team-container">
        <p class="card-details-team">Team 1</p>
      </div>
      <p class="card-details-next-game">Next game: tomorrow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="my-card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
      <p class="card-details-name">Player 2</p>
      <div class="card-details-team-container">
        <p class="card-details-team">Team 2</p>
      </div>
      <p class="card-details-next-game">Next game: tomorrow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="my-card">
    <div class="card-details">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x50" />
      <p class="card-details-name">Player 3</p>
      <div class="card-details-team-container">
        <p class="card-details-team">Team 3</p>
      </div>
      <p class="card-details-next-game">Next game: tomorrow</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well to start with you're assigning rather than testing equality.

```
if(innerDivs[i].innerHTML == "Team 2")
```

should be the pattern you use.

That said, this is super fragile; I can't help but wonder if you wouldn't be better off assigning a classname to each element that matches the team, and then just styling that class accordingly. No JS needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! The only issue here is the team names are being pulled in via API so they are dynamic in nature and referring to a block of reusable HTML to make up the cards for each player brought in

Comment: That doesn't change my point, Angular data binding was built with that exact scenario in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I am following. If the data is not yet output, how am I supposed to style it based off of a <div>'s content without JS?

Comment: Sorry, I was crossing this post with another one with my Angular comment.  If you're using pure JS then you'll still need to set the values of things with your own JS code, but you're still better off setting the style by injecting a CSS classname into the element rather than directly setting the style properties of said elements.  So, for example if you know ahead of time what the team names will be (as implied by your loop) then when you set the content of the element to "Team 2", you can also set the className of the same element to "team-2" which has a style definition in CSS.